# Stop execution of update query without where clause in Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible to set a rule in MariaDB to stop execution of update query without where clause? Like mariadb can stop insert of a record if it doesn't satisfy a foreign key constraint.

I am using Mariadb 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name is `sql_safe_updates`. It can be set at runtime on session or global level:

```
-- for the current session
SET SESSION sql_safe_updates = ON;

-- for future sessions
SET GLOBAL sql_safe_updates = ON;
```